# ¿Cómo imprimo la cabecera y las líneas de un CSV que cumplen una condición?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Estoy intentando limpiar los datos utilizando un while/for en bash o awk. La verdad es que soy nuevo en bash y me es un poco dificil. Estoy tratando con un conjunto de datos como el siguiente:

```
%mpg,cylinders,displacement,horsepower,weight,acceleration,model year,car name
18.0,8,307.0,130.0,3504.,12.0,70,"chevrolet chevelle malibu"
15.0,8,350.0,165.0,3693.,11.5,70,"buick skylark 320",
14.0,8,454.9,220.0,4354.,9.0,70,"chevrolet impala"
...
```

Mi idea es recorrer el archivo `.csv` para obtener otro nuevo que solo contenga aquellos coches que son chevrolet. En este sentido varias cosas:

1. Quitar las comillas del campo car name
2. Si para la línea en cuestión el campo contiene chevrolet nos quedamos la linea en caso contrario, saltamos a la siguiente.
3. Obtener el nuevo archivo limpio.

Hasta el momento he hecho lo siguiente:

```
#!bin/bash
filename="auto_usa.csv"
while IFS=, read -r line; do
     if [["$line" == *"chevrolet"*]]; then
      printf '%s\n' "$line"
     fi
done < $filename
```

Mi problema en general es que estoy acostumbrado a Python/R y nose en este caso como acceder a las variables dentro del fichero para insertar condiciones dentro del while. El caso planteado en esta situación es este, pero si por ejemplo quisiera aplicar un while (bash) o for (awk) para filtrar los coches que tienen más de X `acceleration`. Me encontraria en la misma situación. Me podriais explicar como funciona a partir de este ejemplo? Gracias.

La salida deberia ser algo como:

```
%mpg,cylinders,displacement,horsepower,weight,acceleration,model year,car name
    18.0,8,307.0,130.0,3504.,12.0,70,chevrolet chevelle malibu
    14.0,8,454.9,220.0,4354.,9.0,70,chevrolet impala"
    ...
```

Nota: Seguramente haya formas más fáciles de hacer esto pero el problema que intento solucionar es entender los while/for junto con sentencias if. Gracias.

Comment: en una pregunta anterior ya limpiaste las comillas en un campo, ¿no?

Comment: en Awk, todo va por registros y campos: un registro viene a ser la línea entera y un campo, cada uno de los valores resultantes de separar el registro por un delimitador. En `$0` tienes el registro y en `$1` el 1.º campo, en `$2` el 2.º y así sucesivamente.

Answer (score 1):

En Awk, de forma rápida:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR>1 && $NF !~ /chevrolet/ {next} {gsub(/"/, "", $NF)}1' fichero
```

Lo que hace es:

- Define "," como separador de entrada y salida
- Salta las líneas en las que el último campo no contenga "chevrolet"
- Elimina las comillas dobles del último campo ([fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19474877/1983854))
- Imprime finalmente

Comment: Pero en este caso estas usando awk sin for ni while. En este caso explicito, me gustaria aplicar un while o for para entender mejor la sintaxis. Hay alguna forma de reproducirlo con un while o for? O si no es este caso en particular, como seria un while para filtrar las linias donde el campo acceleration es mayor a X?

Comment: es que no tiene sentido usar awk con un for on un while, @Panri93, complica las cosas. Es mejor usar cada herramienta para su utilidad

Comment: estoy de acuerdo contigo. Sin embargo, para este ejercicio lo que más me interesa (aparte de solucionarlo) es aprender el uso de while y for. Ahora he modificado el código incluyendo la sentencia condicional, sin embargo, cuando lo ejecuto me dice "orden no encontrada". Si pudieras modificar el código que the he proporcionado para realizar lo mismo que tu has propuesto seria genial.

Comment: Ah, ya veo. Simplemente debes poner espacios antes y después de los corchetes: `[[ "$line" == *"chevrolet"* ]]`.

Comment: Nótese que también puedes decir `while IFS=, read -r mpg, cylinders displacement horsepower weight ... car_name` y así cada valor estará en una variable diferente.

Comment: deja de dañar' podrias darle una ojeada e este post? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/459477/filtrar-dataset-mediante-bucle-for-awk 
Gracias

Comment: @Panri93 lo miro. Lo que quiero dar a entender con mi comentario anterior es que el for para procesar líneas con Awk no es necesario. Puede serlo para iterar sobre campos de un mismo registro y cosas así.