# ¿Cómo muestro solamente las líneas en que un campo es mayor que la media de todas las filas?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bucle-for, awk

Soy nuevo en awk. Estoy intentando comprender la sintaxis de awk en el uso de "for". Tengo un dataset como el siguiente:
%mpg,cylinders,displacement,horsepower,weight,acceleration,model year,car name
18.0,8,307.0,130.0,3504.,12.0,70,"chevrolet chevelle malibu"
15.0,8,350.0,165.0,3693.,11.5,70,"buick skylark 320",
14.0,8,454.9,220.0,4354.,9.0,70,"chevrolet impala"

Lo que quiero es calcular la media y filtrar el dataset por aquellos valores que cumplan con la condición de **acceleration > media (acceleration)**. Hasta el momento he hecho lo siguiente:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS=","}
#Calculamos la media
{sum+=$6;media=sum/NRs}  END { print "Average = ",sum/NR}
{for(i=1; i<=NR; i++){if($6 > media) print}}
```

Sin embargo, no funciona adecuadamente y me muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La salida para el ejemplo dado seria:

```
%mpg,cylinders,displacement,horsepower,weight,acceleration,model year,car name
18.0,8,307.0,130.0,3504.,12.0,70,"chevrolet chevelle malibu"
15.0,8,350.0,165.0,3693.,11.5,70,"buick skylark 320",

Ya que la media de acceleration es 10.83
```

¿Qué esta pasando?

Comment: La calculo sobre el campo acceleration.

Comment: entiendo que donde dices NRs, debe ser NR

Comment: Es buena práctica comentar y/o aceptar las respuestas que recibiste

Answer (score 2):

Dado que no puedes saber la media hasta que has leído todo el fichero, puedes o bien almacenarlo todo en memoria, o bien usar una técnica explicada en [Idiomatic awk](https://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/) consistente en pasar dos veces por el fichero: la primera vez calculas cosas y la segunda imprimes lo que cumple la condición dada:

```
# define separador de entrada
BEGIN{FS=","}
# en la primera pasada, suma el 6.º campo a partir de la 2.ª línea
FNR==NR && NR>1{sum+=$6; next}
# cuando termine la primera lectura del fichero, calcula la media
ENDFILE{if (FNR==NR) avg=sum/(NR-1)}
# en la segunda pasada, solo imprime aquellas líneas 
# en las que el 6.º campo sea mayor a la media
NR>1 && $6 > avg
# imprime la media
END{printf "\nya que media... es %.2f\n", avg}
```

Y lo ejecutas como `gawk '...' fichero fichero`. (Necesitas GNU Awk para lo de `ENDFILE`).

En una línea:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} FNR==NR && NR>1{sum+=$6; next} ENDFILE{if (FNR==NR) avg=sum/(NR-1)} NR>1 && $6 > avg; END{printf "\nya que la media de acceleration es %.2f\n", avg}' fichero fichero
%mpg,cylinders,displacement,horsepower,weight,acceleration,model year,car name
18.0,8,307.0,130.0,3504.,12.0,70,"chevrolet chevelle malibu"
15.0,8,350.0,165.0,3693.,11.5,70,"buick skylark 320",

ya que la media de acceleration es 10.83
```

---

Ahora, ¿por qué no funciona tu código?

Dices así:

```
BEGIN {FS=","}
#Calculamos la media
{sum+=$6;media=sum/NRs}  END { print "Average = ",sum/NR}
{for(i=1; i<=NR; i++){if($6 > media) print}}
```

Fíjate que escribes `END { ...}` y después el bucle `{for(i=1; i<=NR; i++){if($6 > media) print}}`. Lo que estás haciendo en este bucle es iterar sobre todos los campos de cada línea, de ahí que te imprima repetidamente la misma línea.